# What to return for the non-async path?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function returning the promise returned by `$timeout`. This function also has another code path that bypasses the `$timeout` call.

In order to maintain the promise-based API, what should I return in this latter path?

```
function foo() {
  if(bar) {
    return $timeout(fn);
  }

  return ?; // I want to maintain the promise API. This code path is expected to be synchronous.
}
```

Comment: `Promise.resolve(some-value)`

Comment: Where `Promise` is supplied by AngularJS?

Comment: see angular documentation - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: although dirty, you could return $timeout(function(){});

Comment: `$q.resolve(some-value)`

Comment: @JaromandaX Please make your comment the answer.

Comment: Do a `return $q.when('return value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for ES6 promise use:

```
function foo() {
    if(bar) {
        return $timeout(fn);
    }
    return Promise.resolve(some-value);
}
```

for AngularJS, you can use

```
function foo() {
    if(bar) {
        return $timeout(fn);
    }
    return $q.resolve(some-value);
}
```

or

```
function foo() {
    if(bar) {
        return $timeout(fn);
    }
    return $q.when(some-value);
}
```

$q.resolve is an alias of $q.when